# Hide button in odoo security file

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

Is it possible hide button in odoo ir.model.access.csv security file.

For example on form I have two button (Button 1 and Button 2) admin can see both button, user only Button 1.

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are buttons on a form view you can show *Button 2* only for certain user groups for by adding a [`groups` attribute](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#structural-components) on it, eg.:

```xml
<button string="Button 2" groups="base.group_system" name="..." type="..."/>
```

This will only show *Button 2* to users belonging to the *Administration -> Settings* group.